# Update Nexus 7 to Android Kitkat

Tags: android, android-4.4-kitkat

How Can I update the Nexus7 to Android Kitkat? I know  that there in no official google Version , but is there a way I can update thru Eclipse?

Comment: This would better be posted on http://android.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about upgrading Android and should be asked on [Android.stackexchange](http://android.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 3):

The Nexus 7 is a stock Android device, or a Google Play device. This means that it will be getting the Android KitKat (4.4) update in the coming days. You are much better off waiting for the update from Google than installing a ROM on your phone, as it may contain hidden viruses. As @damryfbfnetsi said, this question should belong on [android.stackexchange.com](http://www.android.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 1):

First you have to unlock your device. Its easy with this utility: `http://www.wugfresh.com/nrt/`

After that you have to download custom ROM. It depends if you have

1. classic (non 3g) Nexus 7: http://forum.xda-developers.com/nexus-7/orig-development
2. 3g version Nexus 7: http://forum.xda-developers.com/nexus-7/3g-development

Look for ROM with 4.4 Kitkat in thread name. I also advise to read comments in forum thread before you download it.

Again to flash custom ROM use wugfresh utility.